# How prevent my app content from apps that has “SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW” permission

Tags: android, video-recording

I am implementing a **video streaming App** and want to secure my content
I have used

```
 getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

It stopped taking screenshot of app, but if recording app start before my app user can hear content

And some apps able to record video.

I thought to prevent other apps that has '**SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW**'  *permission* from **capturing** my content, so i want to know how to do that?

**Note**: MinSdk is 21

Answer (score -1):

### Checking if you have the drawOverlays permission is safer using this:

```
public static boolean canDrawOverlayViews(Context con){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT< Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){return true;}
        try { 
            return Settings.canDrawOverlays(con); 
        }
        catch(NoSuchMethodError e){ 
            return canDrawOverlaysUsingReflection(con); 
        }
    }
    
    
    public static boolean canDrawOverlaysUsingReflection(Context context) {
    
        try {
    
            AppOpsManager manager = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
            Class clazz = AppOpsManager.class;
            Method dispatchMethod = clazz.getMethod("checkOp", new Class[] { int.class, int.class, String.class });
            //AppOpsManager.OP_SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW = 24
            int mode = (Integer) dispatchMethod.invoke(manager, new Object[] { 24, Binder.getCallingUid(), context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() });
    
            return AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED == mode;
    
        } catch (Exception e) {  return false;  }
    
    }
```

### Requesting the permission:

```
public static void requestOverlayDrawPermission(Activity act, int requestCode){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + act.getPackageName()));
    act.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);

}
```

Comment: this is to know apps that have that permission but how to prevent them from captuing my content

Comment: also some apps can capture content without have that permission

Comment: It is possible if you on android 4.4+, you can specify MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT

Comment: could u please explain more `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT`

Answer (score -1):

### It is possible if you on android 4.4+, you can specify MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT

> Starting in Android 4.4, the owner, group and modes of files on
> external storage devices are now synthesized based on directory
> structure. This enables apps to manage their package-specific
> directories on external storage without requiring they hold the broad
> WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. For example, the app with package
> name com.example.foo can now freely access
> Android/data/com.example.foo/ on external storage devices with no
> permissions. These synthesized permissions are accomplished by
> wrapping raw storage devices in a FUSE daemon.

Comment: where to use `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT`